# Append string to user agent within Service Worker

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, service-worker

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. I have researched in depth and have spent a lot of time looking at similar questions on SO - but unsuccessful.

A bit of background. I have a website and an android app which effectively renders the website in a different form with different displays etc... The app knows to do this from incoming requests - as users have a particular string appended to the user agent (let's just say that string is 'MobileAppRequest'). Upon detecting this string in the user agent, the server knows to return a different html file. This allows the user to still go to the website on their browser and use the web version as well as have the app experience from their android app.

Now, upon using a service worker, it defaults to the user's standard user agent without including the appended string from the app. This then returns the web version within the app which messes it all up. I need to know how to set custom headers, or indeed, append a string to the user agent within the service worker. It says the headers are immutable when i try to directly change it but i know a way around this is to make a new request as a response.

Here is my SW.js

```
var CACHE_STATIC_NAME = 'static-v10';
var CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME = 'dynamic-v2';

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Installing Service Worker ...', event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_STATIC_NAME)
      .then(function (cache) {
        console.log('[Service Worker] Precaching App Shell');
        cache.addAll([
          '/',
          '/static/media/next.png',
          '/static/media/previous.png'
        ]);
      })
  )
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Activating Service Worker ....', event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys()
      .then(function (keyList) {
        return Promise.all(keyList.map(function (key) {
          if (key !== CACHE_STATIC_NAME && key !== CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME) {
            console.log('[Service Worker] Removing old cache.', key);
            return caches.delete(key);
          }
        }));
      })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request)
      .then(function(res) {
        return caches.open(CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME)
                .then(function(cache) {
                  cache.put(event.request.url, res.clone());
                  return res;
                })
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        return caches.match(event.request);
      })
  );
});
```

I would appreciate the answers contain either the full sw.js or the whole function you're editing just so i don't make any mistakes integrating back into the code.

Comment: If the user's browser registers the service worker, why not pass the browser's user agent when creating the service worker? Then you don't have to deal with the SW user agent.

Comment: What do you mean by 'pass' browser's user agent? How can this be achieved?

Comment: With `postMessage()`, is one way.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can pass the whatever data you want to the Service Worker if you use `postMessage()`.

Below is an example using your script.

*webpage.html*

```
<script>
  // creates ServiceWorker
  var worker = new Worker('SW.js');
  // sends the browser's userAgent to the ServiceWorker
  worker.postMessage(window.navigator.userAgent);
</script>
```

*SW.js*

```
var CACHE_STATIC_NAME = 'static-v10';
var CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME = 'dynamic-v2';
// defines a global variable that will hold the UserAgent
var UA = '';

// listens to incoming postMessage()
self.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  // update the UA variable with the event.data, which is the browser's UserAgent
  UA = event.data;
  console.log('ServiceWorker now has UA variable defined as ', UA);
}, false);

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Installing Service Worker ...', event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_STATIC_NAME)
      .then(function (cache) {
        console.log('[Service Worker] Precaching App Shell');
        cache.addAll([
          '/',
          '/static/media/next.png',
          '/static/media/previous.png'
        ]);
      })
  )
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Activating Service Worker ....', event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys()
      .then(function (keyList) {
        return Promise.all(keyList.map(function (key) {
          if (key !== CACHE_STATIC_NAME && key !== CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME) {
            console.log('[Service Worker] Removing old cache.', key);
            return caches.delete(key);
          }
        }));
      })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  // var myHeader = new Headers(event.request.headers);
  // myHeader.append('CUSTOMHEADER', 'CUSTOMVALUE');
  // you can now make a request using the passed UA
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request, {credentials: 'same-origin', mode: 'cors', redirect: 'follow', userAgent: UA}).then(function(res) {
        return caches.open(CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME)
                .then(function(cache) {
                  cache.put(event.request.url, res.clone());
                  return res;
                })
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        return caches.match(event.request);
      })
  );
});
```

While browsing SO is great for examples, sometimes it's better to reference the documentation when you have limited options.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your code to add custom header in fetch request. You should try with it, It'll work.

For your use case, you want to add custom header for your domain request only, so I've added a regex check which will check and add custom header to fetch requests pertaining to your domain only. (added localhost for local testing). For fetch requests pertaining to other domain, it'll send standard headers.

You need to pass some additional parameters to fetch call, which I've added.
In you application, edit 'CUSTOMHEADER', 'CUSTOMVALUE' and YOURDOMAIN.com as you want.

Read more about Header() at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers.
In case you want to modify useragent, add following lines in fetch event in the answer,

```
  var myHeader = new Headers(event.request.headers);
  myHeader.delete('User-Agent');
  myHeader.set('User-Agent', 'CUSTOM_USERAGENTVALUE');
```

Please Note: Altering "User-Agent" is not recommended as of now, as recently it was removed from list of prohibited header. So browser support is limited.

```
var CACHE_STATIC_NAME = 'static-v10';
var CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME = 'dynamic-v2';

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Installing Service Worker ...', event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_STATIC_NAME)
      .then(function (cache) {
        console.log('[Service Worker] Precaching App Shell');
        cache.addAll([
          '/',
          '/static/media/next.png',
          '/static/media/previous.png'
        ]);
      })
  )
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Activating Service Worker ....', event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys()
      .then(function (keyList) {
        return Promise.all(keyList.map(function (key) {
          if (key !== CACHE_STATIC_NAME && key !== CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME) {
            console.log('[Service Worker] Removing old cache.', key);
            return caches.delete(key);
          }
        }));
      })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    if(/^.*\:\/\/(?:localhost|YOURDOMAIN\.com)\/.*/.test(event.request.url))
    { var myHeader = new Headers(event.request.headers);
      myHeader.append('CUSTOMHEADER', 'CUSTOMVALUE');
      console.log('Custom Fetch Call:'+event.request.url);
      event.respondWith(
        fetch(event.request.url, {credentials: 'same-origin', redirect: 'follow', headers: myHeader}).then(function(res) {
            return caches.open(CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME)
                    .then(function(cache) {
                      cache.put(event.request.url, res.clone());
                      return res;
                    })
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            return caches.match(event.request);
          })
      );
      return
    }
    event.respondWith(
      fetch(event.request).then(function(res) {
        return caches.open(CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME)
                .then(function(cache) {
                  cache.put(event.request.url, res.clone());
                  return res;
                })
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        return caches.match(event.request);
      })
    );  


});
```

You can check it on service `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_CUSTOMHEADER'];` , it will echo `CUSTOMVALUE`. I've cross verified its working through server side and on chrome network panel.

In order to serve custom app page to your android user you should use (IN PHP):

```
$INSIDEAPP = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'CUSTOMUSERAGENT') !== false))? true:false;
$INSIDE_SW = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CUSTOMHEADER']))?true:false;

$SERVE_APP_PAGE = $INSIDEAPP || $INSIDE_SW;

if($SERVE_APP_PAGE)
{
//serve request of app page.
}
else
{
// serve normal request through browser
}
```

Comment: Did it work for you? didn't work for me. Cors error, even when i change mode to no-cors. it says: The FetchEvent for "<URL>" resulted in a network error response: an "opaque" response was used for a request whose type is not no-cors. Plus, the custom headers don't get added (i check using console log of user agent on load of homepage after sw is registered).

Comment: I've edited the code and removed mode:'cors'. I've also checked the code, it is working properly and adding custom headers as defined. Note: you need to refresh the page once after initial load in order to see it working. On initial page load service worker activates and on subsequent page load service worker intercepts requests and add header.

Comment: I updated it with this code and still it shows same standard UA. I refresh after the sw is registered but still the console log shows same UA. Did you test this on chrome? How did you verify that your headers were changed after tweaking the sw?

Comment: I'll not recommend you to change user agent on service worker request, as it may not work in some old browser, since it was in restricted list and has been removed recently. You can add custom header on fetch call and on server side, serve app page to requests containing your custom useragent (which was set in android webview) as well as requests with custom header.

Comment: I've again edited the code and added a fetch match pattern with other tweaks. I've cross verified it's working on server side as well as on chrome panel. Since, on chrome panel sometimes it doesn't shows request headers. you should try now with edited code.